# charts.js not loading in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, chart.js

I am using charts.js to make a chart in django. My `index.html` loads but the chart doesn't load. I can't figure out why its not working. I am using `pipenv shell` to make the virtual environment, but still no luck for some reason. I have my static folder holding my `main.js`, this is what's generating the graph. My urls are good because it shows my `<h1>` tag, but just no graph. in my terminal i do see `"GET /static/main.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0`

INDEX.HTML

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>index</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'main.js' %}"></script>
    
</head>

<body>
<h1>index</h1>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

MAIN.JS

```
let labels1 = ["YES", "NO"];
let data1 = [50,50];
let colors1 = ['#49A9EA', '#36CAAB'];


let myChart1 = document.getElementByID("myChart").getContext('2d');

let chart1 = new Chart(myChart1), {
    type; 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: labels1,
        datasets: [{
            data: data1,
            backgroundColor: colors1
            }]
    },
    options: {
        title: {
            text: "DO YOU LIKE DOUGHNUTS?"
            display: true;

        }
    }
});
```

URLS.PY

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index")
]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `canvas` element is not loaded yet, wrap your `main.js` code in `DOMContentLoaded` callback function

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
    // wrap your js code here
}, false);

// with jQuery 
$(document).ready(function(){ /* ... */ });

// shorter
$(function(){ /* ... */ });
```

### Update

Also check your js code

```
let ctx = document.getElementById('pie-chart').getContext('2d');
let chart1 = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Comment: I still get the same result.

Comment: @pete800 it seems that your in your js code, you have accidentally added an **')'**  after **myChart1**,  `let chart1 = new Chart(myChart1), config)` , Chart needs two parameters, `context, config`

Comment: That is a good spot, thank you. unfortunately still not loading.

Comment: @pete800 specify the `height` and `width` for the canvas then and check the docs if you missing something, I can not find other errors. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/